Где можно доходчиво разобрать строение процессора?
Я изучаю работу с языками ассемблера, и поэтому мне необходимо глубокое понимание работы процессора, строения его регистров, их назначения и т.д. В той книге по которой я учусь конечно есть эта тема. Но пока что, она разбирается не особо понятно. Я конечно понимаю, что процессор эта та дичь которую никогда нельзя будет назвать простой для понимания, но всё же. Где можно наиболее доходчиво изучить строение процессоров? (желательно что бы в этом ресурсе приводились какие нибудь ассоциации для лучшего понимания)

уточните пожалуйста какой процессор вы изучаете? процессоров много и есть микроконтроллеры в которых то же есть процессоры :) архитектура построения процессора??? от этого зависят и ответы а рассказать абстрактно о всех процессорах не представляется возможным :)
Самая полная информация находится в документах от производителя процессора.

Книга КОД Чарльза Петцольда

https://nandgame.com/

https://store.steampowered.com/app/1444480/Turing_Complete/

кмк, нет лучше учебника чем опыт, а потому резервируем в расписании 140+ часов, 400$, паяльник, и топаем в первую попавшуюся статью формата собираем свой ЦП из гхм... и палок, например в эту в подобных статьях обычно базовый материал есть, максимально ужат и изложен с необходимым минимумом канцелярита. ах да, если написанное не только читать но и делать, на выходе вполне может остаться что-то работающее, собранное своими руками, пригодное для "потрогать" и местами даже понятное :3 потом стоит почитать и про VHDL, машинный код, инструкции
